# executeScript WebDriver

Tags: javascript, webdriver

I want to use WebDriver to execute some javascripts on the application i am testing.
Im using the following code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String label = (String)js.executeScript("return document.g.nodes[1].label", null);
```

g global javascript object in the page. if i inspect it from the console using inspect elements i see that everything is there...
though when i execute this script im thrown an exception stating "Cannot create node property from undefined".

Witch g is for some reason undefined in the page.

anyone have any ideas?

its not a problem with timing since im working in debug and manually wating for page to load completly.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Aren't javascript objects attached to window rather than document?

At least I have always used window.whatever from webdriver and it works nicely.

Comment: What is the difference between window and document? More precisely difference between document.activeElement and window.activeElement